# Set “product_visibility” in Woocommerce according to metadata in _stock_status

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

In WooCommerce I'm using scraping/import plugin which doesn't recognise and I can't insert **outofstock** meta based on actual stock in the **"product_visibility"** taxonomy.

The thing is, that all out of stock products are hidden when the **stock status** is **Out of stock**, but products are still counted in the product categories. If  `_stock_status` product metadata is **outofstock**, the **`product_visibility`** `outofstock` post term **should be also set for the product**.

**My Question is:**
How to set the missing **`product_visibility`** `outofstock` post term when the product **`_stock_status`** metadata is set as **`outofstock`**?

I was trying something with code below. I'm not a programmer, but my logic was to get term in _stock_status... but It doesn't work :/

```
function wc_update_300_product_visibility() {
  global $wpdb;

  WC_Install::create_terms();

  $featured_term = get_term_by( 'name', 'outofstock', '_stock_status' );

  if ( $outofstock_term ) {
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "INSERT IGNORE INTO {$wpdb->term_relationships} SELECT post_id, %d, 0 FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_key = 'product_visibility' AND meta_value = 'yes';", $featured_term->term_taxonomy_id ) );
  }
}
```

Comment: Dont ask again [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61509962/set-product-visibility-in-woocommerce-to-out-of-stock-from-outofstock-metada) … Edit your original question instead looking to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ... Once done, click on reopen button.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec ...I didn't get what was the reason for closing the first one and I'm really stuck here whit this problem. So that's why I asked again.

Comment: AS this problem is quiet complicated, nobody has answered you… Your question has been closed because your are supposed to provide your code attempt in your question and to better explain things and context. Nobody can reproduce your problem, because you were using an outdated third party plugin... Only few questions are answered in StackOverFlow.

Comment: I've tried several php functions and I wasn't even sure which one could be on the right track. So I asked a general question how to make product_visibility to inherit data from stock_status in Woocommerce. This doesn't have anything with "outdated" plugin. the plugin is just the reason why i need to populate product_visibility  in a different way.

Comment: I think I know what you are talking about. Are you still interested in this topic?